# Very interesting behavior of an IC

Tags: batteries, integrated-circuit, soldering

well an IC bring me from a my friend who is workin in a toys company for kids. this IC is coming as almost ready from Chine, all soldering parts are ready and than the company only soldering the battery pins and establish. this IC is a part of kid toys which is cell phone toys and it has touch pad etc.

The problem of this IC is very strange. After all parts establishng and battery connected to device, device not start to working. After removing battery and waiting 10 minute and inserting batteries to device again, the device start to working. I actually did not understand why it works after removing the battery and waiting for 10 minutes when we put the battery back in. ( if we rapidly remove and put battery device also not working).

what is the problem do you have any idea. or how to fix it

this is device an IC photos.

[image]

the company only soldering this battery cable right side, (not IC side)

[image]

this is close look to IC

[image]

Comment: Almost impossible to say with such limited information.

Comment: Many of us use term IC for integrated circuits. The circuit board in your not fully assembled device probably contains a  few of them + a bunch of simpler components. Of course the naming conventions are culture dependent, so do not let our peculiarities disturb you in using terms in a way which is common where you live.

Comment: maybe you have bad cells ... 10 minutes rest time probably recovers some of the function

Comment: The Chinese reads "Turkey Mobile Phone!" :)

Comment: @tlfong01 Yes, Turkey (the country, not the bird). But why?

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany, well, just to give more clues. So it should be a Turkish speaking mobile phone made in a toys factory.

Comment: @tlfong01 Ah, a Turkish-speaking toy mobile phone. Makes sense.

Comment: @JohnD What kind of information do you need? I'll try to find

Comment: What is that part on the right which 2 red cables go through?

Comment: @mehmet Information that you unfortunately don't have :)  Like a datasheet for the IC and a schematic, though the schematic looks easy enough to deduce if you had info on the IC.  Using new batteries and reflowing all the solder joints would probably be a good start.

Comment: @Ayhan açma kapama tuşu. power key

Answer (score 2):

Totally speculative here, and your photo is not very clear, but the symptoms sound like an improper reset and one of the solder connections looks pretty dubious:

[image]

Maybe try re-flowing the joint on that capacitor if the solder joint looks that bad in real life. Though it looks like a supply bypass part it might affect reset.

Comment: thanks, after your answer, I have checked the this capacitor. at the "continuous test" its beeping continuously the leads of the meter are continuous in one direction. If I change the places of the leads I touched the capacitor, this time no beep is heard.. and doesn't show any farad while I am measuring the capacitance